# Extracting unique values from a range of cells across multiple pages.

Tags: excel, indexing, max, countif

I currently have a table with 5 columns. The 2nd and 3rd columns have values which change depending on the 5th column's value. See below:

Sheet1:

```
1    A       B        C         D        E
2    #      Red     Yellow      #      Orange
3    #     Yellow    Blue       #      Green
4    #      Red      Blue       #      Purple
5    #     Green     Blue       #      Blue-Green
6    #     Yellow   Orange      #      Yellow-Orange
```

On my second sheet, I have another table with quantity, name, and description.
See below:

Sheet2:

```
      A           B              C              D
1    Qty        Name        Description        Cost
2     #           -            Text            Text
3     #           -            Text            Text
4     #           -            Text            Text
5     #           -            Text            Text
6     #           -            Text            Text
```

Currently my Qty, Description, and Cost columns all fill automatically using vlookup with 'Sheet2'B# as my query (depending on which row it's in) and a table on a third page.

What I'm looking to do, is have the "Name" column fill automatically, with the unique values from 'Sheet1'B2:C6.

The formula would leave the table looking like this:

Sheet2:

```
      A           B              C                       D
1    Qty        Name         Description                Cost
2     2         Red       Namebrand Red paint       Red paint cost
3     3         Blue      Namebrand Blue paint      Blue paint cost
4     1        Orange     Namebrand Orange paint    Orange paint cost
5     3        Yellow     Namebrand Yellow Paint    Yellow paint cost
6     1        Green      Namebrand Green Paint     Green paint cost
```

A search yielded this array formula, which uses named ranges:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(ECM, MATCH(MIN(IF(COUNTIF($B$1:B1, ECM)=0, 1, MAX((COUNTIF(ECM, "<"&ECM)+1)*2))*(COUNTIF(ECM, "<"&ECM)+1)), COUNTIF(ECM, "<"&ECM)+1, 0)), "")
```

"ECM" is my named range of B2:C6, but this returns nothing, regardless of what's in the cells B2:C6.

As I said, I have the formulas for columns A, C, and D. Just the unique values are throwing me off.

Comment: I have but to no avail. Excel does append the curly brackets, but it doesn't change the result. Dragging the

Comment: How does one correct this?

Comment: Please let me know which part, I'll try to explain it a little better.